# Is it cryptographically secure to replace the numbers in a sha-256 hash with non hex alpha characters?

Tags: security, hash, sha256, sha

Fairly simple question here but wanted to make sure there isn't some aspect to this I'm not thinking of that makes this a terrible idea.

Let's say I have a SHA-256 hash:
`7fe3add3b08cf7efd042771ca4c6987a37db9f9cc253a40e741dfe8b04d3b19b`

Is it any less secure, prone to collisions, or is any other downside to replacing each digit in the hash with a non-hex (non a-f) alpha character not in the hash as it is? i.e. replacing 0-9 => g-p? In this case converting the hash to:
`nfejaddjbgocfnefdgkinnhcakcmponajndbpfpcciljakgenkhdfeobgkdjbhpb`

In theory I don't off hand see how this would be less secure, but wasn't able to find any real information about doing something like this online.

Answer (score 1):

A 1:1 mapping of characters as you propose wouldn't add or remove any information from the original hash, and would be functionally identical to the original hash (e.g., just as secure). These modified hashes would essentially have all of the same properties as the originals, just using a different set of 16 characters.

The main downside that I can think of is that introducing these "alpha-only" hashes could be confusing since they are obviously non-standard, particularly if they were to get intermingled with hashes that did not have their numeric characters replaced. Depending on how you are interacting with these hashes, code that deals with them might need to be "aware" of whether the digits have been replaced or not, introducing more complexity where there otherwise would not be.